# How to detect View pager vertical swipe and send that event to the layout below ?

Tags: android

I have one `view` that has some vertical `gestures` like swipe down to move the `view` down etc. lets call this View `rootView`. Everything was good util I needed to add a view pager on top of it. Now the `ViewPager` is consuming all the touch events. The `ViewPager` is scrolling horizontally as it should, but consuming the vertical swipes too and doing nothing (not passing the event to the rootView). How to make both the Views listen to their corresponding touch events and send the rest to other. I tried creating a CustomViewPager and overriding its `onTouchEvent` in the hope of recognizing the swipe down first and `return false` in that case so that the rootview will get a chance to handle that touch event. But in the process of recognizing the gesture as down/up , the `ViewPager` is consuming `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_MOVE` event which are needed by the `rootView` to process the amount of finger movement.

A solution that came to my mind is to add `onTouchEvent` on all the `layout` over the `ViewPager`, which recognize the `Vertical` vs `horizontal` and call the appropriate touchevent (of `rootView` vs `ViewPager`) , but in order to recognize the up/down/side gesture, the `layout` will consume some events which may be valueable to the `rootView`.

Another solution that comes to mind is to override the `ontouchEvent` of `ViewPager` and call the `onTouchEvent` of the rootView irrespective of the up/down/side movement. In this way both the `ViewPager` and `rootView` can use the event, but it is sometimes making the screen fluctuates.

How should I solve this problem ? I would appreciate some suggestions, and no need to provide the code, just a good way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've had to completely modify my original answer. My first solution was to subclass ViewPager and override `onTouchEvent()`, adding logic to switch between the `CustomViewPager` and the `RelativeLayout` below it. Returning `false` means the view ignores the event, and returning `super.onTouchEvent(event)` means the view consumes the event until the user lifts their finger. All the logic was in the `ACTION_MOVE` part of the event, but since you only get one chance to return a value (which is the first part of the event, `ACTION_DOWN`), you can't use any movement to determine whether to consume or ignore the event.

I finally got it to work by writing an entirely new class, starting with the `ViewPager` code and adding logic to recognize vertical gestures. When a vertical gesture occurs, code is run that acts on the `RelativeLayout` below it, instead of passing the touch event to it. Below is a code snippet from the `onTouchEvent()` of my class.

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewGroup {

    // code from ViewPager class...

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (!mIsBeingDragged) {
                if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "!mIsBeingDragged");

                final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(ev, mActivePointerId);
                final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, pointerIndex);
                final float xDiff = Math.abs(x - mLastMotionX);
                final float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(ev, pointerIndex);
                final float yDiff = Math.abs(y - mLastMotionY);
                if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Moved x to " + x + "," + y + " diff=" + xDiff + "," + yDiff);
                if (xDiff > mTouchSlop && xDiff > yDiff) {
                    isVerticalMovement = false;
                    hasMovedHorizontally = true;
                    if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Starting drag!");
                    mIsBeingDragged = true;
                    requestParentDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    mLastMotionX = x - mInitialMotionX > 0 ? mInitialMotionX + mTouchSlop :
                            mInitialMotionX - mTouchSlop;
                    mLastMotionY = y;
                    setScrollState(SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING);
                    setScrollingCacheEnabled(true);

                    // Disallow Parent Intercept, just in case
                    ViewParent parent = getParent();
                    if (parent != null) {
                        parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (yDiff > mTouchSlop) {
                        // VERTICAL SWIPE -- do stuff here...
                    }
                }
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing the `rootView` on top of the `ViewPager`?

That way, the `ViewPager` should still work although being under the `rootView`